# Can the whole prologue be skipped with other method than using saves?

Tags: steam, pc, deus-ex-human-revolution

Every time I restarted the game, I had to go through the whole "walking cinematic" with Dr. Reed, where the game doesn't prompt any means to skip it.

The reason why I'm asking about not using a save method, is because of the use of mods: he game crashes when loading an unmodded game or one that won't coincide with game's mechanics.

I was wondering if devs made about some deep mechanism about it (maybe a hidden console thing, starting the game with parameters, etc) though I haven't found any so far.

Game has some modding potential, but it seems that nobody made a mod to skip the whole prologue (starting at Sarif, augmented, 6 months later).

Answer (score 4):

It does not seem so. However, by using a [glitch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsObXRSf830), you can skip most of it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, though not ideal, is to install the [**Map Selector**](https://forums.eu.square-enix.com/showthread.php?t=128155) mod. After all, debug menus are dev/cheat tools.

If never played before, the player would have the power to be auto-spoiled by the places the player would go through canonically. Also, once inside the menu, the player cannot exit the menu until choosing a map!

Lucky for me, I finished this game a long time ago, and judging by the start of the map selector's menu, it's in canon-chronological order. Also has an unused, more tutorial-oriented version of the prologue-escape map.

Comment: Do be careful of choosing to install the Debug Menu mod (displayed in the linked post). Personally I got tempted trying some stuff from the get go as soon as I opened it, and ended up with Steam rewarding me the [Transhumanist](https://steamcommunity.com/stats/DXHR/achievements/) achievement (getting all upgrades of an aug) by accident, when all I wanted was to try removing the Infolink augment to see how the game would respond.